# KeyError: EOFerror while taking input from user

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am creating a game that

1. Asks how many players are there.
2. Asks user to select theme for the game
   After asking a question to the user
3. Ask user to provide answer within 5 seconds.

I am facing problem in 3rd step specifically getting input from user.

Here's how my code looks like:
`askAnswer()` is used to ask user to provide input.

```
def askAnswer():
    
    try:        
        ans = input("Enter Answer[A,B,C,D] ")
        tm.flag = True
        print("Here")
        return ans
    except Exception as e:
        print("In except.")
        return e
```

`checkAnswer()` uses the input provided by all the players and assign scores.

```
def checkAnswer():
    for i in range(NumberOfPlayers):
        ans = askAnswer()
            if i == 0:
                if questions["questionbank"][index][ans] == answer:
                    print("test")
                    p1scr=p1scr+1
```

So after I enter an answer I get an error:

```
ERROR:app:Exception on /round [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "app.py", line 221, in startRounds
    p1scr, p2scr, p3scr, p4scr= getAnswer(questions, answer, index)
  File "app.py", line 158, in getAnswer
    print(questions["questionbank"][index][ans])
KeyError: EOFError()
```

Update:
I am using `omxplayer` to play sound. So user has to provide input with in 5 seconds. The `omxplayer` I think takes control of the command line which doesn't allow user to give the input. Is there any solution to this? How can I make the player play in the background.

I don't know if its storing the input or not.
I have been stuck at this problem for very long. Please let me know any ideas on how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, see if you still get the error if you skip checkAnswer() and the for loop. If so, revise your question to focus on the minimal code you need to get the error.  If not, revise your question to include the tests you've done.

Next, put a print statement immediately after the input() call. Just print a static string, NOT ans.  Put a second statement inside your except -handling block with a print for a different static string. This will tell you whether your error is in input() or something else.

Third, that very broad "except Exception as e: return e" is likely to hide the true error. Make it very specific to the line and type of exception you want to handle. You should almost always do something different inside the exception handler. Returning the exception or "pass" almost always makes existing problems worse.  If you think the Exception comes from input(), that should be the only line between "try" and "except". Specify the exception as "InputError", "ValueError", or whatever specific type gets raised without it, and choose an action based on the conditions that cause that error.

Comment: Great. A lot of things I didn't know. Thank you. I'll follow what you said and update my post accordingly.

Comment: I used your second suggestion and updated the answer.